# Exclude some ABI provide versions from system

Tags: linux, rpm

How can I exclude **libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)** from provides list:

```
# rpm -q --provides libstdc++
libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6
libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.1)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.2)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.3)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.1)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.10)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.12)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.13)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.2)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.3)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.4)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.5)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.6)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.7)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.8)(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit)  
libstdc++ = 4.4.5-6.el6
libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.4.5-6.el6
```

Building rpm packages on my system, and didn't know is it possible to manage provides of ABI versions (exclude or delete from system), and how if so?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible using rpm foo (because rpm extracts these provides from so objects) unless you build RPM again after removing corresponding API or make it private (via patch and apply that patch before build (before %build section).